# link error using AVRoutePickerView

Tags: ios, objective-c, linker-errors, avkit

I am trying to use AVRoutePickerView in my app but when I build the project I am getting linking error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
"_OBJC_METACLASS_$_AVRoutePickerView", referenced from:
  _OBJC_METACLASS_$_PttVolumeView in PttVolumeView.o
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_AVRoutePickerView", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in SettingsVolumeCell.o
  _OBJC_CLASS_$_PttVolumeView in PttVolumeView.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see 
invocation)
```

This is AVKit library. I don't understand why I am getting it?
Can someone help?

Thanks in advance and regards

Answer (score 1):

I have finally found solution,
Just adding AVKit framework to Embedded and Linked libraries in
project settings